# confluent-kafka-python consumer unable to read messages

Tags: python, ssl, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am stuck with an issue related to Kafka consumer using confluent-kafka's python library.

**CONTEXT**
I have a Kafka topic on AWS EC2 that I need to consume.

**SCENARIO**
Consumer Script (my_topic_consumer.py) uses confluent-kafka-python to create a consumer (shown below) and subscribe to the 'my_topic' topic. The issue is that the consumer is not able to read messages from the Kafka cluster.

All required security steps are met:
1. SSL - security protocol for the consumer and broker.
2. Addition of the consumer EC2 IP block has been added to the Security Group on the cluster.

```
#my_topic_consumer.py
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError

c = Consumer({
  'bootstrap.servers': 'my_host:my_port',
  'group.id': 'my_group',
  'auto.offset.reset': 'latest',
  'security.protocol': 'SSL',
  'ssl.ca.location': '/path/to/certificate.pem'
})

c.subscribe(['my_topic'])

try:
  while True:
    msg = c.poll(5)
      if msg is None:
        print('None')
        continue
      if msg.error():
        print(msg)
        continue
      else:
        #process_msg(msg) - Writes messages to a data file.

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print('Aborted by user\n')

finally:
  c.close()
```

**URLS**
Broker Host: my_host
Port: my_port
Group ID: my_group

**CONSOLE COMMANDS**
*working* - Running the console-consumer script, I am able to see the data:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server my_host:my_port --consumer.config client-ssl.properties --skip-message-on-error --topic my_topic | jq
```

Note: client-ssl.properties: points to the JKS file which has the certs.

Further debugging on the Kafka cluster (separate EC2 instance from consumer), I couldn't see any registration of my consumer by my group_id (my_group):

```
kafka-consumer-groups --botstrap-server my_host:my_port --command-config client-ssl.properties --descrive --group my_group
```

This leads me to believe the consumer is not getting registered on the cluster, so may be the SSL handshake is failing? How do I check this from consumer side in python?

**Note**
- the cluster is behind a proxy (corporate), but I do run the proxy on the consumer EC2 before testing.
- ran the process via pm2, yet didn't see any error logs like req timeouts etc.

Is there any way I can check that the Consumer creation is failing in a definite way and find out the root cause? Any help and feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to consume from `'earliest'` (instead of `'latest'`) offset ?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous: no, I have tried ```'earliest'``` with no luck :(